# Linux Raw Socket Permissions Issue

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I'm creating a raw ethernet socket in a C application, e.g.

```
s = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ALL));
```

and its returning -1 indicating an error

I'm pretty sure its a permissions issue - You can only open a raw socket if you have a UID of 0 (root) or have the `CAP_NET_RAW` capability

I don't think running the application as root is reasonable, therefore my question is how can I 'add' the `CAP_NET_RAW` capability permission to my user account?

From http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man7/packet.7.html

```
   In order to create a packet socket, a process must have the CAP_NET_RAW
   capability in the user namespace that governs its network namespace.
```

But how does one achieve that end?

Comment: running the application as root only until you obtain this resource and then "giving up" those root privileges by means of `seteuid()` is possible.

Comment: this link seems to explain how to assign the appropriate capability without resorting to running as root via the setcap cmd - you seem to associate the appropriate raw socket capabilities with a specific executable -> http://packetlife.net/blog/2010/mar/19/sniffing-wireshark-non-root-user/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You set the capabilities on the executable that needs that capability, not a user account. The syntax is

```
setcap cap_net_raw,cap_net_admin=eip ./your_exeutable
```

(Note, you need to run setcap as root, so use e.g. `sudo setcap ...` Also make sure there are no space characters in `cap_net_raw,cap_net_admin=eip`

Comment: brilliant - same conclusion i came to - theres an additional bit in here -> http://packetlife.net/blog/2010/mar/19/sniffing-wireshark-non-root-user/ about creating a new group and adding the exe to it - so a user would have to be a member of that group in order to have the permission to run it - i guess its another layer of security which is prob no bad thing?

Comment: while i'm pretty sure this is the correct answer, unfortunately I still can't implement it as setcap isn't working for me - i think I have some kernel configuration issue that needs fixing prior to it working (see comments associated with other setcap answer) Maybe have to post another separate question for that ;)

Comment: This doesn't seem to suffice on Debian 11 (Linux 5.16.0-6); Still results in `EACCESS` when creating the socket.

Answer (score 4):

Being able to read **all** network packets is considered a severe security risk, that is why this needs a privileged account.

You can make the application "suid root" to elevate your own rights when starting this application as a "normal" user. But that is a security risk as well and needs a bit of thorough thinking when designing the application (it should at least give up the higher privilege as soon as it doesn't need it any more - i.e. after having opened the raw socket).

Comment: ah ok - so running as root is the only real solution to this problem?

Comment: one thing i did note en route to this problem was that wireshark can run as non-root and pick up raw ethernet packets - I wonder how that works?

Comment: do an `ls -ls wireshark` and you'll most probably find it uses exactly what I have proposed

Comment: Is the requirement to read raw packets the same as reading all network packets? What I need to be able to do is read/write packets specifying a MAC address rather than an IP address

Comment: are you sure you cannot? maybe via setcap on linux kernels > 2.2?

Comment: the wireshark thing involved runing -> sudo usermod -a -G wireshark $USER i.e. adding my user to the wireshark group - possibly the wireshark group has elevated priveleges? I did take a look in /etc/group and found -> wireshark:x:130:me

Comment: `setcap` is a Linux-specific "finer-granular" setuid, in principle. It creates non-portable programs, but can do what you want.

Comment: ls -ls wireshark gave -> 20 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 16786 Jun  1 07:05 init.lua so maybe that is running as root after all?

Comment: related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/455478/what-is-setcap-command-and-file-capability

Answer (score 2):

You cannot add the `CAP_NET_RAW` permission to your account, because capabilities on Linux do not follow users. They follow executables.

To make this work, you need to add the `CAP_NET_RAW` capability to your compiled executable. See the `setcap` command in order to see how to do that.

Comment: thanks for clarification - I now understand that capabilities are added to executables rather than users

Comment: Now getting this error -> sudo setcap 'cap_net_raw, cap_net_admin=eip' my_exe
fatal error: Invalid argument
usage: setcap [-q] [-v] (-r|-|<caps>) <filename> [ ... (-r|-|<capsN>) <filenameN> ]

 Note <filename> must be a regular (non-symlink) file.

Comment: the exe isn't a symlink - looks like others have had similiar issues - looks like the answers potentially here -> https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-842057-start-0-postdays-0-postorder-asc-highlight-.html but I don't really understand the /proc dir yet..

Comment: I have succesfully used getcap i.e. getcap /usr/bin/dumpcap
/usr/bin/dumpcap = cap_net_admin,cap_net_raw+eip

Comment: i'd like to set the same capabilities for my executable thats doing the raw socket stuff but I can't because of the aforementioned error..